# How exactly do I get VS Code debugging to work with docker compose and NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, debugging, docker-compose

I've been following the Microsoft supplied guide for docker compose [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/docker-compose#_debug) with VS Code. I've followed each of the steps successfully but, for some reason I cannot seem to get VS Code debugging working for my docker compose configuration. I can get docker compose to run, but when I attach to the container, I can never seem to hit any breakpoints? When I run the typescript debug configuration that I have setup in my `launch.json`, I can hit breakpoints and see logging just fine, so I know it's not VS Code that is the issue, so it must be something I'm doing incorrectly? Could it be that since I'm using typescript, I need to set debug points in the generated JS files instead of the original typescript?

I've attached my `launch.json`, `tasks.json` and `docker-compose.yml` files below, thanks for any help you can give.

launch.json

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "preLaunchTask": "Compose Up (Dev)",
            "postDebugTask": "Compose Down",
            "localRoot": "{workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Typescript",
            "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/dist/bot.js",
            "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - src/tsconfig.json",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/src/.env.development.local",
            "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"],
            "resolveSourceMapLocations": ["${workspaceFolder}/**", "!**/node_modules/**"],
            "console": "internalConsole"
        },
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Compose Up (Dev)",
            "type": "docker-compose",
            "dockerCompose": {
                "up": {
                    "detached": true,
                    "build": true,
                    "profiles": [
                        "dev"
                    ]
                },
                "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/src/.env.development",
                "files": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/docker-compose.yml"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Compose Down",
            "type": "docker-compose",
            "dockerCompose": {
                "down": {
                    "removeVolumes": true,
                    "removeImages": "all"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
services:
    prisma-studio:
        container_name: prisma-studio
        image: timothyjmiller/prisma-studio:latest
        restart: unless-stopped
        depends_on:
            postgres:
                condition: service_healthy
        profiles:
            - dev
        environment:
            POSTGRES_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}
        ports:
            - ${PRISMA_STUDIO_PORT}:${PRISMA_STUDIO_PORT}
    postgres:
        image: postgres:12.14
        container_name: postgres
        hostname: postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_USER_PASS}
            POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
        ports:
            - ${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}
        restart: 'unless-stopped'
        volumes:
            - 'postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -q -d $$POSTGRES_DB -U $$POSTGRES_USER"]
            interval: 10s
            timeout: 5s
            retries: 5
    futababot:
        build: .
        container_name: futababot
        depends_on:
            postgres:
                condition: service_healthy
        tty: true
        env_file:
            - src/.env.development
volumes:
    postgres-data:
```